# Difference between FF and Chrome/Edge XSLT engine with regards to inserted '</tr><tr>' text

Tags: firefox, xslt, html-table

I'm experiencing problems with the XSLT engine in Firefox. If you open a `< tr >` element and insert `< /tr > < tr >` as text instead of  a `< td > < /td >` element, this is interpreted as text and does not produce a "carriage return".

Comment: Well, why would you want a table row without any cells?

Comment: Please show us minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT code, result you want and the one you get, plus information on how you run the XSLT transformation (`xml-stylesheet`, Javascript) inside the browser. Is the rendering of the XSLT produced HTML any different in Firefox compared to using the same in a plain HTML document?